# append new path in variable assignment in multiple scripts

Tags: linux, perl, unix

I have an environment variable declared in my perl scripts which are like below. This variable can be slightly different in different perl files.
In first file:

```
$ENV{MY_LIBS} = "$MY_PATH/bin:$HOME/PACKAGE1:$HOME/PACKAGE2";
```

In Second file:

```
$ENV{MY_LIBS} = "$MY_PATH/bin:$HOME/MYLIBS1:$HOME/PACKAGE2";
```

Now say I want to append `$MY_PATH/lib` to all such files so that they would be like:

In first file:

```
$ENV{MY_LIBS} = "$MY_PATH/bin:$HOME/PACKAGE1:$HOME/PACKAGE2:$MY_PATH/lib";
```

In Second file:

```
$ENV{MY_LIBS} = "$MY_PATH/bin:$HOME/MYLIBS1:$HOME/PACKAGE2:$MY_PATH/lib";
```

How can I do this with some simple command in Linux ?

Comment: `perl -i -pe 's|^(\$ENV{MY_LIBS} = "[^"]+)|$1:\$MY_PATH/lib|' *.pl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Perl "one-liner"](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) in lieu of a "*simple command in Linux*"

```
perl -i.bak -pe's/\$ENV{MY_LIBS}.*\K"\s*;/:$MY_PATH\/lib";/' file1 file2 ...
```

I assume that `$MY_PATH` stands for a literal string, otherwise I don't know where it'd come from.

The switches mean:

- `-e` signifies that what follows inside `''` is evaluated as Perl code, so the program follows
- `-p` opens given files and loops over lines so that the code in `''` is applied successively to each line; the processed line is printed at the end
- `-i` makes it edit input files "in-place" (they're changed) and with `.bak` backup is kept

Code comments:

The [lookbehind](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind)-type construct [\K](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Lookaround-Assertions) drops all previous matches, so nothing is "consumed" out of the string before it; thus the replacement part tacks on the desired string. We do need to put back `";` since that was matched after `\K` and was thus removed from the string (when matched).

Comment: Thanks your answer and explanation was helpful .